vcpkg_execute_required_process not setting OUTPUT_VARIABLE?
I'm not very familiar w/ cmake or vcpkg, but I've been assigned to work on a task to build some libraries using a tool which wraps the latter.
My goal, in the interests of perhaps helping me solve this XY problem, is to follow the directions from https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/icu4c/build.html#how-to-build-and-install-on-windows-with-cygwin, which tell you to run vcvars<ARCH>.bat before running configure.
My constraint is that I have to implement the build process from within a vcpkg 'port' .cmake file, so I can't simply CALL the batch file directly to affect vcpkg/cmake's environment.
My idea was to run another shell script which runs vcvars<ARCH>.bat & then echo the relevant details to stdout, and to have cmake parse that output & explicitly set the environment based on that.
My new script which implements that idea, called GetVCVars.bat looks like
@ECHO off

REM Run the VS batch script (the path to which should be the first & only parameter provided to this script) to set up the environment
CALL %* >NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
ECHO %* failed with error %ERRORLEVEL% 1>&2
EXIT /B 1
)

REM Print out the relevant environment variables to stdout
SET | FINDSTR /R /X /C:"PATH=.*" /C:"INCLUDE=.*" /C:"LIB=.*" /C:"LIBPATH=.*" /C:"PLATFORM=.*" /C:"VS[0-9]*COMNTOOLS=.*"
EXIT /B 0

The relevant fragment of associated cmake logic is
# Output is of the form of key=value, one variable per line
set(VCVARS_SCRIPT "${VCVARS_SCRIPT_DIR}/../../../../../../Auxiliary/Build/vcvars${SIMBA_TARGET_BITNESS}.bat")
vcpkg_execute_required_process(
  COMMAND cmd /c GetVCVars.bat "${VCVARS_SCRIPT}"
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CURRENT_PORT_DIR}
  LOGNAME GetVCVars-${TARGET_TRIPLET}-${VCPKG_BUILD_TYPE}
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE VC_VARS
)

message(STATUS "VC_VARS = '${VC_VARS}'")

# Iterate over each line/variable definition
string(REGEX MATCHALL "[^\r\n]+" VC_VAR_DEFS "${VC_VARS}")
foreach(VC_VAR_DEF IN LISTS VC_VAR_DEFS)
  if(NOT ${VC_VAR_DEF} MATCHES "^([^=]+)=(.*)$")
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Unexpected line returned from GetVCVars.bat: ${VC_VAR_DEF}")
  endif()
  
  message(STATUS "Setting '${CMAKE_MATCH_1}' to '${CMAKE_MATCH_2}'")
  set(ENV{${CMAKE_MATCH_1}} ${CMAKE_MATCH_2})
endforeach()

The weird thing is, that when I test this, that I get the output -- VC_VARS = '' (Which I interpret to mean that the output variable I told vcpkg_execute_required_process to fill w/ the stdout of the invoked command was either not set, or set to an empty string???), even though a file called GetVCVars-build_configuration-release-out.log gets created with the content
INCLUDE=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\ATLMFC\include;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\ATLMFC\include;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um
LIB=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\ATLMFC\lib\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\lib\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.22621.0\ucrt\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.22621.0\\um\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\ATLMFC\lib\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\lib\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.22621.0\ucrt\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.22621.0\\um\x64
LIBPATH=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\ATLMFC\lib\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\lib\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\lib\x86\store\references;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.22621.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.22621.0;C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\ATLMFC\lib\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\lib\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\lib\x86\store\references;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.22621.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.22621.0;C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
VS170COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\Tools\
PATH=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX64\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VC\VCPackages;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\bin\Roslyn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Common\VSPerfCollectionTools\vs2019\\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Common\VSPerfCollectionTools\vs2019\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\x64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\HTML Help Workshop;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\FSharp\Tools;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Team Tools\DiagnosticsHub\Collector;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\CodeCoverage.Console;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64;C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\Tools\;C:/bitbucket/packagey/vcpkg/downloads/tools/python/python-3.11.5-x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX64\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VC\VCPackages;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\bin\Roslyn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Common\VSPerfCollectionTools\vs2019\\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Common\VSPerfCollectionTools\vs2019\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\x64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\HTML Help Workshop;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\FSharp\Tools;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Team Tools\DiagnosticsHub\Collector;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\CodeCoverage.Console;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64;C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\Tools\;C:\bitbucket\packagey\vcpkg\downloads\tools\powershell-core-7.2.16-windows;C:\Program Files\OpenLogic\jdk-11.0.21.9-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files\OpenLogic\jdk-8.0.392.08-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files\Python312\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Python312\;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-11.0.21.9-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.8.101-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.392.8-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.392.8-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jre-8.0.392.8-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jre-17.0.8.101-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jre-11.0.21.9-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse Adoptium\jre-8.0.392.8-hotspot\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Perforce\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Strawberry\c\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\site\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Microsoft Application Virtualization\Sequencer\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLIV2\;C:\Users\matthew.wozniczka\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\ripgrep-13.0.0-i686-pc-windows-msvc;C:\Program Files\OpenLogic\jdk-11.0.21.9-hotspot\bin\server;C:\Users\matthew.wozniczka\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Dr. Memory\bin\;C:\Users\matthew.wozniczka\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\matthew.wozniczka\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\Ninja;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VC\Linux\bin\ConnectionManagerExe;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\vcpkg;C:/bitbucket/packagey/vcpkg/downloads/tools/ninja/1.10.2-windows;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\Ninja;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VC\Linux\bin\ConnectionManagerExe;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\vcpkg

(i.e. what I expected)
I don't understand what I've done wrong (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/maintainers/functions/vcpkg_execute_required_process#output_variable)?

So you basically want:
a) This https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/e2b7713d2f49bbda5781f072fe21240e37cb3996/ports/vcpkg-fortran-ifort/z_vcpkg_load_environment_from_batch.cmake
or
b) set(VCPKG_LOAD_VCVARS_ENV ON) in a triplet https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/users/triplets#vcpkg_load_vcvars_env
or
c) A custom build of vcpkg with https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg-tool/pull/1315 merged where you can directly set env variables
